# Analysis of Universal Hashing

Tags: algorithm-analysis, hashing

I was reading universal Hashing from *Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et al.*, and came across the following corollary regarding search, insert and delete functions on Universally Hashed tables:

> ***Corollary 11.4***
>
> Using universal hashing and collision resolution by chaining in an initially empty table with $m$ slots, it takes expected time $\Theta(n)$ to handle any sequence of $n$ **Insert**, **Search**, and **Delete** operations containing $O(m)$ **Insert** operations.
>
> ***Proof*** Since the number of insertions is $O(m)$, we have $n = O(m)$ and so $\alpha = O(1)$. The **Insert** and **Delete** operations take constant time and, by Theorem 11.3, the expected time for each **Search** operation is $O(1)$. By linearity of expectation, therefore, the expected time for the entire sequence of  $n$ operations is $O(n)$. Since each operation takes $\Omega(1)$ time, the $\Theta(n)$ bound follows. $\quad\blacksquare$

1. How is the author able to say that $n = O(m)$, in the first line of the proof?
2. Also, what does $n=O(m)$ mean? Because $n$ is a variable and $m$ is a constant, therefore the statement seems wrong.
3. Also, if $n=O(m)$ is true, then obviously $n=\Omega(m)$ is true, thus yielding $n=\Theta(m)$.

Comment: I think $n$ is being used with two different meanings: it is both the occupancy of the table and the length of the sequence.

Comment: The statement "$n = O(m)$" means "there exists a constant $C$ such that $n \leq Cm$". The constant $C$ depends on the hidden constant of $O(m)$ in the statement of the corollary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement of the corollary is extremely sloppy. Here is a correct statement and proof.

> ***Corollary 11.4***
>
> Fix $c < 1$. Using universal hashing and collision resolution by chaining in an initially empty table with $m$ slots, it takes expected time $\Theta(N)$ to handle any sequence of $N$ **Insert**, **Search**, and **Delete** operations containing at most $cm$ **Insert** operations.
>
> ***Proof*** Since the number of insertions is at most $cm$, we have $n \leq cm$, where $n$ is the number of elements in the table, and so the load factor satisfies $\alpha \leq c$. The **Insert** and **Delete** operations take constant time and, by Theorem 11.3, the expected time for each **Search** operation is $O(1)$. By linearity of expectation, therefore, the expected time for the entire sequence of  $N$ operations is $O(N)$. Since each operation takes $\Omega(1)$ time, the $\Theta(N)$ bound follows. $\quad\blacksquare$

Roughly speaking, there are two problems with the book version:

1. The variable $n$ is used both for the number of elements in the table and for the number of operations.
2. The number of Insert operations should be $O(m)$, **with a hidden constant bounded away from $1$.**

Comment: Thx for the explanation, I understood the proof . But why are we restricting $C < 1$ , because that says that the number of elements in the table can never be greater than the number of slots. Even if we have $C\geq 1$ the proof seems to be working as we still have $\alpha \leq C$ for some constant $c$ therefore $\alpha =O\left( 1\right) $ , and the rest follows . P.S Thx for referring the textbook for me and correcting the question .

Comment: Suppose we put 200 items in a hash table whose capacity is 100 items. Would anything go wrong?

Comment: Understood the hash table overflows , usually even our hash function gives wrong keys . But even if it gives keys within $h(k)$ such that $h\left( k\right) \in \left[ \begin{matrix} 0& \ldots .& m-1\end{matrix} \right] $ load factor increases .

Comment: Because we use chaining for dealing with collisions I thought that hash table overflows are also allowed. I read the net hash tables overflows are usually not allowed

Comment: You might be right. It depends on how the hash table is implemented exactly. Since only you have a copy of the book, I’ll let you figure that out.